# Odoo 8 KeyError on Custom Module on "Upgrade Module"

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have a related field set-up and works fine when the field is added to FormView via GUI in developer mode. However, when I added the fields to custom module and tried to do an Upgrade, it breaks with KeyError on x_work_order_num. What am I missing?

Some other notes:

- odoo-server restarted after changes to .py
- Fields exist in Settings > Database Structure > Models and Fields
- Adding x_rel_order and x_ext_num to FormView via Edit FormView (Developer Mode) works but Upgrade via Local Modules throws the above error.
- Error occurs before "onchange" method was implemented.

**my_sale.py**

```
class my_sale_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    _columns = {
        'x_work_order_num': fields.char('Work Order Number', size=64),
        }
```

**my_invoice.py**

```
class my_account_invoice(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'
    _name = 'account.invoice'

    x_rel_order = fields.Many2one('sale.order', 'Related Sales Order')
    x_ext_num = fields.Char(related='x_rel_order.x_work_order_num', string ="External Number")

    @api.multi
    def onchange_x_rel_order(self,order_id,context=None):
        work_order_num = ""

        if(order_id):
            p = self.env['sale.order'].browse(order_id)
            work_order_num = p.x_work_order_num

        res = {
            'value': {
                'x_ext_num': work_order_num
          }
        }

        return res
```

**my_invoice.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <openerp>
        <data>
          <record id="invoice_form_my" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
            <field name="name">account.invoice.form</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
              <xpath expr="/form/sheet/group/group[2]/field[@name='account_id']" position="after">
                <field name="x_rel_order" on_change="onchange_x_rel_order(x_rel_order)"/>
                <field name="x_ext_num" readonly="1"/>
              </xpath>
            </field>
          </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

**__openerp__.py**

```
{
'name': 'My_Invoicing',
'version': '1.0',
'category':'Sales',
'description': 'My custom module',
'author': 'jeszy',
'depends':['base','sale','account','account_voucher'],
'data': ['my_invoice.xml'],
'demo': [],
'installable': True,
'auto_install': False,
}
```

**Odoo Error:**

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 539, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 576, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 312, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 309, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 805, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 405, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 948, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 534, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_upgrade, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 495, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 370, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 351, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 255, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 156, in load_module_graph
    registry.setup_models(cr, partial=True)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 194, in setup_models
    model._setup_fields(cr, SUPERUSER_ID)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 372, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3006, in _setup_fields
    field.setup(self.env)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 468, in setup
    self._setup_related(env)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 514, in _setup_related
    field = recs._fields[name]
KeyError: 'x_work_order_num'
```

Comment: see my answer here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747250/database-schema-changed-now-odoo-wont-run/36747462#36747462   and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618984/parseerror-invalid-view-definition/36624531#36624531

Comment: Maybe you need to change the order in the __init__.py file? :)

Comment: @PrakashSharma: Restarted server many times. Does not work. Unfortunately, responses in the provided link do not work for my case....

Comment: @dccdany: __init__.py under the module's folder? I have these dependencies in __openerp__.py (migrated from OpenERP 7 to Odoo 8):

{
'name': 'My_Invoicing',
'version': '1.0',
'category':'Sales',
'description': 'My module',
'author': 'jeszy',
'depends':['base','sale','account','account_voucher'],
'data': ['my_invoice.xml'],
'demo': [],
'installable': True,
'auto_install': False,
}

Comment: inside the fields menu http://prnt.sc/as5264  search your field name, is it present or not

Comment: for now just remove the on change from the view let me know is it working or not

Comment: can put your module in a public git repo , bcz i can't help you from here

Comment: please print error message too

Comment: @BaijuKS error added

Comment: please add init.py in your module

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly something that some may be looking for but in my case, what I've needed was solved by replacing the definition of

```
x_ext_num = fields.Char(related='x_rel_order.x_work_order_num', string ="External Number")
```

with

```
x_ext_num = fields.Char(string='External Number', compute='_compute_x_ext_num')
```

I didn't need the related option and tied an on_change in the XML to a method:

```
@api.multi
def onchange_x_rel_order(self, order_id, context=None):
    ext_num = ''

    if(order_id):
        p = self.env['sale.order'].browse(order_id)
        ext_num = p.x_work_order_num

    res = {
            'value': {
                'x_ext_num': ext_num
          }
    }

    return res


def _compute_x_ext_num(self):
    for record in self:
          p = self.env['sale.order'].browse(record.x_rel_order.id)
          record.x_ext_num = p.x_work_order_num
```

Comment: i am using the custom module with odoo 13 getting           KeyError: 'product_id'
the field alredy in the model 
view model code   <field name="model">account.move</field>

model account.move

product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Product')

@jeszy can you please answer on it